# How to load Excel file into temp table in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, temporary-tables, excel

Is it possible to load a excel file with the headers into a temp table on Oracle?

I use TOAD for the interface.

I am needing to do some comparison on a a excel file with what we have in our database. Unfortunately, the data that is in the excel file is NOT in our database but in order for me to report on data, I need to bring it in for comparison.

Is this doable? If so, what would the appropriate approach be for this?

Comment: what tools do you have:  SQL developer, Toad, PL/SQL developer?? they all have built in's to make it easier

Comment: Thank you Kevin, I use TOAD for Oracle. 

I ended up finding out how to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go to the menu and choose: database → create  → table

The follow prompt, choose schema, select object type (view, table etc).

Also make sure your column structure does not interfere with importing since the same rules apply with importing data when it comes to column spaces etc.. (Column names with spaces etc...)